# How to plot a function when we want to change the independent variables?

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation, differential-equations, functions, numerical-integration

Suppose we have two functions $z(x)=x^4+1$ and $y(x)=x^2+x+1$. Then how to plot $z$ vs $y$ (assuming in general that $z$ can not be written explicitly in terms of $y$)?

Comment: `ParametricPlot` ?

Answer (score 1):

Given your definitions

```
eqns = z == x^4 + 1 && y == x^2 + x + 1;
```

you can plot the resulting curve

```
Show[Region[ImplicitRegion[Eliminate[eqns, x], {y, z}]], Axes -> True]
```

[image]

Comment: You could also use `ContourPlot[
 Evaluate@Eliminate[{y == x^2 + x + 1, z == x^4 + 1}, x], {y, 0.7, 
  2}, {z, 0.9, 2}]`